# Low precision from function returning matrix

Tags: functions, matrix, evaluation, precision-and-accuracy, numerical-value

Got a function depending on single parameter "t" defined below which 
 returns a 2 by 2 matrix

```
H[t_] := PauliMatrix[1] (3 - Cos[Pi t]) + PauliMatrix[3];
U[t_] := Total[Map[With[{x = Normalize[#]}, TensorProduct[x, x /. t -> 0]] &, Eigenvectors[H[t]]], 1];
```

When I call the function the result gets rounded to the identity

```
 U[0.2]
 {{1., 0.}, {0., 1.}}
```

But if I use a replacement I get the answer to a suitable precision

```
 U[t] /. t -> 0.2
 {{0.999843, -0.0177345}, {0.0177345, 0.999843}}
```

How do I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

This is *not a precision problem*. You can check that with

```
U[2/10] - U[0.2] // N
```

> {{1.11022*10^-16, 5.55112*10^-17}, {5.55112*10^-17, 1.66533*10^-16}}

`Eigenvectors` simply does not (ortho-)normalize eigenvectors for symbolic input. Mostly because this would blow-up the complexity of the returned expressions even more.

Comment: Im sorry I don't see what your example illustrates. Why does U[2/10] give anything different to U[0.2]? I know Eigenvectors doesn't orthonormalise for symbolic input, which is why I'm forcing it to normalise the symbolic expression? If I evaluate the RHS side with "t' left symbolic, and then define the function from that expression it behaves as I want it to. How do you suggest I write the function?

Comment: Up to machine precision, `U[2/10]` does _not_ give anything different from `U[0.2]`.

Comment: I don't see how you orthonormalize the eigenvectors. Did it occur to you that the replacement rule `t -> 0` does _nothing_ if you call `U` with anything else but `t`? Better use `Orthogonalize`.

Comment: The eigenvectors are automatically orthogonal, so I don't need to worry about that.  The replacement rule does in fact work if I call U with any symbolic input. None of this answers my question.

Comment: Yes you are right: The replacement rule does _something_ also for other symbols. But it does not what you expect for numerical input. Here is something to mull over: `f[t_] := {1, 2, 3, t} /. t -> 0;
f /@ Range[3]
f /@ N@Range[3]`.

Comment: ah apologies your right the replacement rule doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the original code is an evaluation problem.  @Henrik points this out [in a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186430/low-precision-from-function-returning-matrix#comment485718_186431).

The rule `t -> 0` becomes `0.2 -> 0` in the call `U[0.2]`:

```
Hold[U[0.2]] /. DownValues@U
(*
  Hold[Total[(With[{x$ = Normalize[#1]}, 
        x$ \[TensorProduct] (x$ /. 0.2 -> 0)] &) /@ Eigenvectors[H[0.2]], 1]]
*)
```

However the rule is applied to the eigenvectors of `H[0.2]`, which do not contain a `0.2` to replace:

```
Eigenvectors[H[0.2]]
(*  {{0.540734, -0.841193}, {-0.841193, -0.540734}}  *)
```

It's different in the call `U[t]`, in which the rule is `t -> 0` and the eigenvectors of `H[t]` contain a `t` to replace with zero.

One way around the difficulty is to use a different symbol for `t` in `H[t]`.  Formal symbols cannot normally be assigned a value, so `\[FormalT]` is a good candidate:

```
UU[t_] := With[{v = Normalize /@ Eigenvectors[H[\[FormalT]]]},
   Total[MapThread[
     TensorProduct, {v /. \[FormalT] -> t, v /. \[FormalT] -> 0}], 1]
   ];
```

Since `Eigenvectors[H[t]]` is always the same, one might want to precompute the formulas for `U[t]` and use them to define the function `U`.  It's a good idea to protect `t` with [`Block`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html), in case it has been assigned a value.  Also, it turns out formal symbols can be assigned a value by a user with `Block[{\[FormalT] = 5}, <code>]`, so it would be even safer to use [`Module`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) to create a temporary symbol for `H[t]`:

```
Block[{t},
  UU[t_] = Module[{$t, v},
v = Normalize /@ Eigenvectors[H[$t]];
    Total[MapThread[TensorProduct, {v /. $t -> t, v /. $t -> 0}], 1]
    ]
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining the function as

```
 U[t_] := Evaluate[Total[Map[With[{x = Normalize[#]}, TensorProduct[x,x /. t -> 0]] &, Eigenvectors[H[t]]], 1]];
```

gives the behaviour I want. But I still don't understand why the original definition did't work.

Comment: If this resolves your problem, then you should learn about the difference between `Set` (`=`) and `SetDelayed` (`:=`)...